# PythonNN.zip: are PYC files needed

Tags: python, python4delphi

I make Python3+Delphi app. I packed all files+dirs from Libs folder into python32.zip. It works.

- Do I need PYC files (and `__pycache__` dirs) in that zip?
- If I pack PYC files, will Py3k work fasteer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include the pyc files, no.  Assuming, that is, you are adding your zip file to `sys.path` and importing from that (the question could use more details along those lines), the Python zipimporter will gladly compile the bytecode for you on the fly.

You should have a little faster startup time if you include the pyc files (or for a stand-alone application you might consider including .pyo files instead, which you can make in various ways, such as running python with the `-O` flag).  That said this bytecode compilation is pretty fast, so depending on how many modules your application imports it might not make a noticeable difference.  Try it for yourself and see.